# Hooks empty after calling endpoint

Tags: plutus, plutus-pab

I'm finding it difficult figuring out the cause of this hiccup. When I create an instance of a contract, the hooks are populated, but after calling an endpoint, the hooks list becomes empty.

Status of Contract Instance before endpoint invocation:

```
{
    "cicCurrentState": {
        "observableState": null,
        "logs": [],
        "hooks": [
            {
                "rqID": 2,
                "itID": 1,
                "rqRequest": {
                    "aeMetadata": null,
                    "aeDescription": {
                        "getEndpointDescription": "cancel-ob"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "rqID": 1,
                "itID": 1,
                "rqRequest": {
                    "aeMetadata": null,
                    "aeDescription": {
                        "getEndpointDescription": "create-ob"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "err": null,
        "lastLogs": []
    },
    "cicContract": {
        "unContractInstanceId": "a39797ac-bbb6-449b-a389-35b096882df6"
    },
    "cicDefinition": "OB",
    "cicWallet": {
        "getWallet": 2
    }
}
```

After endpoint invocation:

```
{
    "cicCurrentState": {
        "observableState": {
            "ttCurrencySymbol": {
                "unCurrencySymbol": "dffa71c3c512fe6ab8c0d72651a6122fb5d11042ef53d7131a47ca2c"
            },
            "ttOutRef": {
                "txOutRefIdx": 1,
                "txOutRefId": {
                    "getTxId": "b135806142f3d020fc68e9e72fa6e8e7c8fce34b2a0f17fd23b633641f58944a"
                }
            }
        },
        "logs": [
            {
                "_logMessageContent": "OB sent ",
                "_logLevel": "Info"
            }
        ],
        "hooks": [],
        "err": null,
        "lastLogs": []
    },
    "cicContract": {
        "unContractInstanceId": "a39797ac-bbb6-449b-a389-35b096882df6"
    },
    "cicDefinition": "OB",
    "cicWallet": {
        "getWallet": 2
    }
}
```

After calling the endpoint, a `ThreadToken`  is returned, but all hooks are gone, thereby rendering the instance useless.

Example of what happens when an endpoint is called:

```
EndpointCallError (EndpointNotAvailable (ContractInstanceId {unContractInstanceId = a39797ac-bbb6-449b-a389-35b096882df6}) (EndpointDescription {getEndpointDescription = "cancel-ob"}))
```

Comment: Endpoints will become unavailable for a given contract instance id when falling of the *happy path* (e.g. redeemer not validating). I see that you have no errors recorded though.

How do you have your endpoints hooked up and how did you test this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the contract being called from the `ContractInstance` has a delay that listens for change of state of a `StateMachine` until a certain deadline and hence hadn't completely executed the contract, which would consequently enable it publish the hooks and other details relating to the contract.

Calling an endpoint from the same `ContractInstance` led to the error.