# ppp Class 4: What happens when a contract is called while it is not waiting?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

The off-chain contract code is recursive, holds and waits until endpoint is called, then executes code (gets busy for a little while), then recurses.

What happens when a endpoint is called while the contract code is "busy" handling another previous call, hence it is not listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `endpoint` is a `Promise` - which is asynchronous. When called multiple times with different `ContractInstance`, it works without any conflicts.

What happens when an `endpoint` is called twice by the same `ContractInstanceId` can be found [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/hooks-empty-after-calling-endpoint)